# How to check if a post or property has been viewed (on each session)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

I'm using RealHomes Wordpress theme and I want to remember the clicks on each property, but only in one session.

For example, I go to a website to look at some properties, and I click on a few of them, and later when I refresh the page it would say that those properties have been seen, maybe just a text saying "Seen".

And later, or tomorrow, when I go to that same page, all those properties shouldn't have a message "Seen", I want to reset the clicks/views.

I have these two functions in my functions.php file, the getPostViews can be called where you want to display the counter, and setPostViews is called on the beginning of the single.php property file.

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count == '') {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }
    else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }

    add_action('end_session_action','end_session'); 
}

function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I desided to display the clicks on the homepage, next to each property.

[Image: property has been seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV076.png)

[Image: property hasn't been seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58smR.png)

My question is, how can I reset this meta values on each new session?

I also found this code that displays the last time a user visited a website, it resets the clock everytime.

```
function viewed_cookie($postID) {

    // Time of user's visit
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Ljubljana");
    $visit_time = date('d.m.Y. G:i');

    // Check if cookie is already set
    if(isset($_COOKIE['visited_cookie'])) {
        // Do this if cookie is set 
        function postViewed() {

            // Use information stored in the cookie 
            $lastvisit = $_COOKIE['visited_cookie'];
            $string .= $lastvisit; 

            // Delete the old cookie so that we can set it again with updated info
            unset($_COOKIE['visited_cookie']); 

            return $string;
        }   
    } else { 
        // Do this if the cookie doesn't exist
        function postViewed() { 
            $string .= 'New here? Check out these resources...' ;
            return $string;
        }   
    }

    add_shortcode('viewed', 'postViewed');

    // Set or Reset the cookie
    setcookie('visited_cookie',  $visit_time);

}
add_action('init', 'viewed_cookie');
```

How can I merge the set/get functions and use a cookie like in the last example?

Comment: That sounds like it should have worked. So let us see what you did and then maybe we can help

Comment: @RiggsFolly is correct put you html and javascript code for that portion

Comment: I updated my question with some code that works, but I don't know how to use the functions together or merge them. I didn't use javascript, I don't really know javascript that much.